# How to pass parameter programmatically in objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net

I want to pass 3 parameters for SelectMethod and 1 parameters for SelectCountMethod of ObjectDataSource.

How can I pass these? And how ObjectDataSource can distinguish which parameters for which methods?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of passing parameters to an ObjectDatasource.

1) Through it's wizard you can bind the parameters to various controls, form fields, querystring, session, etc.

2) In it's `Selecting` event. Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myObjDs.Selecting += new ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventHandler(myObjDs_Selecting);
        }

void myObjDs_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.InputParameters["someparamname"] = "test";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using selecting event you can also directly add parameters in your button click or anyother function . It must differentiate on the basis of parameter name . I haven't tested it but it shall work.

```
ObjectDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear()
ObjectDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("Parameter1",ValueOfParameter1);
```